# Teamcity 'XML report processing' - Fail Powershell step if tests have failed

Tags: powershell, nunit, teamcity

So I'm manually importing my NUnit results and using the **XML report processing** build feature to process them. However I want to exit a Powershell step if any of the tests have failed (I'm destroying some instance programatically, but would rather keep them for troubleshooting if a test has failed).

The build feature gives me:

```
[Step 1/1] Failed tests detected
```

How can I programatically (in powershell) detect when this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Powershell script is invoking `nunit3-console`, you should examine the return code. A non-zero positive result indicates the number of test cases that failed. A negative result indicates some other kind of error, like file not found.